# Tensorflow Gradient Tape returning None

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow 1.14.0 with Python(3.6.8). I'm trying to use tensorflow_probability's lbfgs optimizer implementation([documentation/example](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/optimizer/lbfgs_minimize)).

If I run the example code provided in the documentation it works fine. I tried to follow the same procedure for my own code which uses the `tf.GradientTape()` approach for computing the objective function. When doing it that way, the gradients come back as `None` type.

I'm not seeing why one is working, but the other is not.

Edit: I realized that running eager execution using the gradients wouldn't work, so I adjusted the example to be able to be run with eager execution.

Non-working example(using GradientTape) with eager execution

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tf.enable_eager_execution()

# A high-dimensional quadratic bowl.
ndims = 3
minimum = np.ones([ndims], dtype='float64')
scales = np.arange(ndims, dtype='float64') + 1.0

# The objective function and the gradient.
def quadratic(x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        value = tf.reduce_sum(scales * (x - minimum) ** 2)
    grads = g.gradient(value, x)
    print('Gradients: ')
    print(grads)
    return value, grads

start = np.arange(ndims, 0, -1, dtype='float64')
optim_results = tfp.optimizer.lbfgs_minimize(quadratic, initial_position=start, num_correction_pairs=10,tolerance=1e-8)

print('results')
print(optim_results)
# Check that the search converged
assert(optim_results.converged)
# Check that the argmin is close to the actual value.
np.testing.assert_allclose(optim_results.position, minimum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to watch x. For the operations inside this context manager, it's required at least one of their inputs is being watched.

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(x)
    value = tf.reduce_sum(scales * (x - minimum) ** 2)
```